# Как создать timeline для сайта

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, вопрос следующего характера. По дизайну на сайте должно быть что то вроде часов времени работы автосервиса, вообще пока нет идеи как это делать, по задумке должна быть привязка к московскому времени и автомобиль с точкой и временем должен перемещаться по линии циклично каждый день. Может есть кто уже делал подобное? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется только показать при открытии страницы можете взять за основу прогресс-бары с UI jQuery. Тут уж фантазия и только. Если хотите анимацию, то добавьте немного js/jquery(данные через ajax подхватывайте)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#tabs
{
font-size:0.7em;
height:500px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabs").tabs();
   $("#pbar1").progressbar({value:50});
   $("#but1,#but2,#but3").button();
   $("#but1").click(function(){ $("#pbar1").progressbar("value", $("#pbar1").progressbar("value")+10)});
   $("#but2").click(function(){ $("#pbar1").progressbar("value", $("#pbar1").progressbar("value")-10)});
   $("#but3").click(function(){alert($("#pbar1").progressbar("value"));});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Пример</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<div id="pbar1"></div>
<br /><br />
<button id="but1">+10%</button>
<button id="but2">-10%</button>
<button id="but3">Сейчас</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Данные пользователь получать может при открытии страницы

Comment: Ок, сейчас попробую по разбираться. Для начала хотя бы без анимации, это уже после можно.